# Why python cant see root direcory of scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy, python-import

I have this
[folder_tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sWJL.png)
and i want to import class from runner.py in crawlers.py

```
from scraper.runner import Runner

runner = Runner([{'name': 'my_name', 'urls': ["https://www.exaple.com/"]}])
runner.crawl()
```

but i got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scraper/crawlers/actor_crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper.runner import Runner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper'
```

Also, i tried relative import:

```py
from ..runner import Runner
```

And got that:

```py
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: have you tried using relative imports? `from .scraper.runner import blah`

Comment: Yeah, i tried, but got this: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following [link](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) to be incredibly helpful in understanding how Python does imports.

The surefire way to ensure your module can be imported though is adding it to os.syspath. Try adding the following to the beginning of your script:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(/path/to/scraper/scraper/runner.py)

from scraper.runner import Runner

runner = Runner([{'name': 'my_name', 'urls': ["https://www.exaple.com/"]}])
runner.crawl()
```

Comment: And i need to do it in all files ? Because in my runner.py i have same stuff 


```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scraper.settings import PATH_TO_PROXY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper'
```

Maybe there is another way to solve it? Change folder stucture maybe?

Comment: Yeah, if you can make your folder structure not rely on accessing a module in a parent directory, that would be ideal. In my experience, importing a module from a parent directory in Python can be pretty rough, and I've only been able to do it via editing os.syspath.